# Unable to execute openssl on AWS lambda: Openssl seems to be removed from node10.x lambda runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, openssl

I am trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/passbook to generate iOS passbook using lambda. The package has the following snippet to sign the manifest:

```
var sign = execFile("openssl", args, { stdio: "pipe" }, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    var trimmedStderr = stderr.trim(); 
    // Windows outputs some unhelpful error messages, but still produces a valid signature
    if (error || (trimmedStderr && trimmedStderr.indexOf('- done') < 0)) {
      callback(new Error(error || stderr));
    } else {
      var signature = stdout.split(/\n\n/)[3];
      callback(null, new Buffer(signature, "base64"));
    }
  });
```

But when I executed it on AWS Lambda (NodeJs 10), I got the following error:

```sh
Error: spawn openssl ENOENT
at /var/task/node_modules/passbook/lib/pass.js:361:16
at exithandler (child_process.js:301:5)
at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:313:5)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

I am thinking the AMI image used does not have openssl installed. Does anyone know if openssl installed and where it is located?

Comment: What do you have in `args`?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58548580/npm-package-pem-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-aws-lambda-nodejs-10-x-results-in-ope