# AWS Lambda openssl x509 error with Node.js 12.x

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, openssl

I am trying to run the follow code to read the cert using openssl. The code is able to work on Lambda at Node.js 8.10.

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

var pemCert = "testCert.cer";

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    return execute('Get Public Key Issuer', 'openssl x509 -in ' + pemCert + ' -noout -issuer -nameopt multiline | grep organizationName')
    .then(result => {
        return (result);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log (error);
    });
};

async function execute(purpose, command) {
    try {
        const {
            stdout,
            stderr
        } = await exec(command);
        console.log(purpose + " : " + command);
        console.log('Execute stdout:', stdout);
        return stdout;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(purpose + " : " + command);
        console.log("Error:" + error);
        throw (purpose + " failed.");
    }
}
```

However, when using Lambda with Node.js 12.x I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: openssl: command not found
```

It seems like AWS is not supporting openssl during runtime in the new Node.js are there any alternatives that can be used to execute openssl commands in Lambda on node 12?

Comment: Chaging the path to:  __dirname + '/openSSL/openssl x509 -in '  seem to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from an email sent by AWS

"We are updating the AWS Lambda and AWS Lambda@Edge execution environment to include recent versions of Amazon Linux and software packages.

A majority of functions will seamlessly benefit from the enhancements in this update without requiring you to take any action. However, in rare cases package updates may introduce compatibility issues. Functions that contain libraries or application code compiled against very specific underlying OS packages, specifically those for **openssl**, glibc, or other system libraries, may potentially be impacted.

Starting May 14, 2019, you can test your functions with the new execution environment. From May 21, 2019, all new functions or updates of existing functions will use the new execution environment. Your existing functions will automatically migrate to using the new execution environment on June 11, 2019."

Another alternative will be use AWS Lambda Layers (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)

You can see the detailed steps here - [NPM package `pem` doesn't seem to work in AWS lambda NodeJS 10.x (results in OpenSSL error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58548580/npm-package-pem-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-aws-lambda-nodejs-10-x-results-in-ope/58965884#58965884)