# How to upgrade openssl on AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, openssl

It seems the runtime used by AWS Lambda has an old OpenSSL library (1.0.2k), but I need the newest 1.1.1k to run my Python program. I currently get this error:

```
DEPRECATION: The OpenSSL being used by this python install (OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017) does not meet the minimum supported version (>= OpenSSL 1.1.1) in order to support TLS 1.3 required
```

I understand we can use Lambda layers to update some dependencies, but I have absolutely no idea how to do this. I tried a tutorial meant for NodeJS but it didn't work (maybe because I'm using Python 3.8 runtime?)

I would appreciate some help in updating openssl

Comment: You can't. BUT: You can run Docker containers in AWS Lambda now. You have full control about the software in a Docker container. Although, I think your issue is that you try to do things at runtime in the Lambda that you should do at build time. Why would you need "python install" in a Lambda. That already sounds like a conceptual problem.

Comment: That's just how Lambda logs the error. I'm not doing anything special at runtime, just importing and using packages. The issue is that the OpenSSL version that the Amazon Linux image has is outdated. I know it's possible to use a newer version because people have done so for NodeJS applications: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58548580/npm-package-pem-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-aws-lambda-nodejs-10-x-results-in-ope/60232433#60232433

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the link. If that helped you, then you should write an answer to your question and accept it.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm too much of a noob to do that for a Python runtime lol. I tried adapting it to Python with no success. I suspect it may have something to do with PATH variables, but I've no idea, I'm a complete noob